# Batch File: Installation was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file, cmd, echo

Error: 
Installation unexpected at this time.

The error occurs in the Highlighted (bold) echo statement after the application is installed when Im running this script on CMD. I have tried with removing @ECHO OFF but didn't seem to work.Please suggest.

Below is the code:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Setting the Package Name
SET PACKAGENAME=OracleCorporation-CrystalBall-11.1.4100.0-EN
SET LOGDIR=%Systemdrive%\Logs\CrystalBall
SET BATCHLOG=%LOGDIR%\%PACKAGENAME%_BatchInstall.log
IF NOT EXIST "%Systemdrive%\Logs\CrystalBall" MD "%Systemdrive%\Logs\CrystalBall"
ECHO %DATE% %TIME% >> %BATCHLOG%
rem Setting the LOGDIR path
SET LOG1=%LOGDIR%\OrcaleCorporation-OracleCrystalBall-EN_Install.log
REM Setting the current directory path
cd /d %~dp0
:Crystal
ECHO Starting installation of Oracle Crystal Ball (32-bit) >> %BATCHLOG%
REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{878FE383-4153-4C76-9F17-F1277FBBD670} /v DisplayName /REG:32
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 GOTO :End
start /wait "inst" "%CD%\Setup\Inst\setup.msi" /qn /L*V %LOG1%
**ECHO completed installing Oracle Crystal Ball (32-bit) with %Errorlevel% >> %BATCHLOG%**
If %Errorlevel% NEQ 0 (
    If %Errorlevel% NEQ 3010 (
        If %Errorlevel% NEQ 1641 (
            ECHO Error occured Ending Oracle Crystal Ball (32-bit) Installation >> %BATCHLOG%
            goto :End
        )
    )
)
:End
ECHO Completed Installation of Oracle Crystal Ball (32-Bit) at %DATE% %TIME% >> %BATCHLOG%
```

Comment: The error is caused by that line, or it never gets to that line?  I'd try changing `/qn` to `/qf` on the previous line and see if you get some useful output, or just investigate the contents of the `%LOG1%` file.

Comment: Crystal Ball is installed. When I tired with **ECHO ON** the above error occurred  by the echo line. However /qn is for silent install as i need to install the application silently whereas /qf will give me a prompt. I checked the log file status shows : **Oracle Crystal Ball (32-bit) -- Installation operation completed successfully.**

Answer (score 1):

the error isn't in the line, you marked, but some lines later at:

```
ECHO Error occured Ending Oracle Crystal Ball (32-bit) Installation >> %BATCHLOG%
```

The closing paranthese `)` closes your `IF` code block (too early) instead of being just echoed. So the word behind (`Installation`) is parsed as a command, which gives you the errormessage.

You have to "escape" this `)` with a caret:

```
ECHO Error occured Ending Oracle Crystal Ball (32-bit^) Installation >> %BATCHLOG%
```

(Note: some people like to also escape `^)`, which is technically not needed, but for symmetry/readability...)

Comment: I thought it might be the parentheses because I've had to escape them, too, just like you say, but since the prior `ECHO` line with parentheses wasn't failing I figured that must not be the issue.  This makes sense.  +1.

Comment: your first `echo` isn't in a code block, so the `)` is "already save".